# Cryptography protocols using graph problem instances

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question, cr.crypto-security

I personally am only aware of basic examples of public key cryptography and I haven't studied cryptography yet. I'm curious if there are circumstances in cryptography where using problem instances from graph theory are preferred to number theory, when building challenges.

(Side question: is number theory generally preferred because the data is more concise and the primitives might be faster in implementation?)

Comment: This may be of interest https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/335.pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number theory (along with neighboring "algebraic" areas like lattices and group theory) gets used for public-key crypto because the problems for which we know *distributions on instances* that (a) are hard and (b) have trapdoors are most naturally stated algebraically. This stands in contrast to the symmetric key setting: a much wider range of natural candidates for one-way functions (which don't require trapdoors) exist.

I imagine one can turn algebraic problems into graph-theoretic ones via the reductions which prove NP-completeness. But those transformations just make the representations more cumbersome -- they don't obviously provide any security advantages.

The eprint paper linked to by Sasho Nikolov in the comments is a good place to look for one of the very few combinatorial alternatives.